# Compose Test rule Ui Testing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, ui-automation, android-espresso, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I am trying to test the compose layout using composeTestRule, I am trying to write a custom matcher to get the following sibling node. Is there any way we can write our own custom matcher to select the next/following sibling node?

Tried to use the getSiblings matcher but its returning all the siblings. But I just wanted the following/ next sibling.